# API response with HTTP 200 with an XML body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, soap, xmlhttprequest, response

How can the `HTTP 200 with an XML body` be sent as the response of an API?
I am working on **rails** and the response of an API is in following format. It means like sending XML message:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <s:Envelope>
     <s:Body>
     </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

But I want to send `HTTP 200 with an XML body instead of this XML Message`.
Please suggest how can this be achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497087/difference-between-sending-xml-body-and-xml-message

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method, do this if the request is successful

```
 @some_response_object = Openstruct.new()

 respond_to do |format|
   format.xml { render xml: @some_response_object }
 end
```

If you want to render a specific xml file, you simply use render, it'll try to find an xml file under the view folder which matches the file path.